# prove the first row of this inverse matrx is positive

Tags: linear-algebra

question:
$B$ is a matrix with all elements of first column is $1$ and others is $0$, $E$ is a identity matrix and $A$ is transition matrix (stochastic matrix). Prove the first row of $(B+E-A)^{-1}$ is positive for any $A$. I use matlab to comfirm this arguement,but I don't know how to decomposite this inverse matrix in a simple way.

Comment: Is A left, right, or doubly stochastic?

Comment: right stochatic

Comment: $(B+E-A)^{-1}$ does not always exist. Consider $A=E$ for instance. Are you assuming that $(B+E-A)^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: yeah, assuming that $[B + E -A]$ is invertible

Comment: Your claim is not true. E.g. when $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1}$, we have $(B+E-A)^{-1}=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&2}$. It is true, however, when $A$ is primitive.